# Paginate through subquery in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.4

The following code will output the 3 first webshops correctly:

```
public function category($slug) {
    $category = Category::select()
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->with(['webshops' => function ($query) {
            $query->groupBy('webshops.id')
                ->where('active', 1)
                ->orderBy('webshops.name')
                ->with(['brands' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('active', 1)
                        ->where('replace_by', NULL)
                        ->orderBy('name');
                }])
                ->paginate(3);
        }])
        ->first();

    if(!$category)
        abort(404);

    $data['title'] = "Tøjbutikker der forhandler ". $category->name;

    $data['category'] = $category;
    $data['webshops'] = $category->webshops;
    return view('pages/category', $data);
}
```

Blade template:

```
                <ul class="webshop-list">
                    @foreach($webshops as $webshop)
                        <li>
                            {{ $webshop->name }}
                        </li>
                   @endforeach
                </ul>
                {{ $webshops->links() }}
```

But when I insert the pagination code in my blade template:

```
{{ $category->webshops->links() }}
```

I get the following error:

```
Method links does not exist.
```

I'm following the documentation from here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [paginator manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator), but if you want to keep code maintainable, just use two collections:

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$shops = Webshop::whereHas('categories', function($q) use($category) {
                 $q->where('id', $category->id);
             })
             ->groupBy('id')
             ->orderBy('name')
             ->with(['brands' => function ($query) {
                 $query->where('active', 1)
                       ->where('replace_by', null)
                       ->orderBy('name');
             }])
             ->paginate(3);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the relation between Category and Webshop is via a relationship table, so what should I replace `where('category_id', $category->id)` with?

Comment: @Christoffer for many-to-many just use `whereHas` instead of `where`. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{{ $category->links() }}
```

`$category` should be your variable name which you're passing to blade.

---

**Example**

If you're passing data like this  `return view('viewName', ['names' => $names]);` then you have to use `{{ $names->links() }}`

---

[Read this Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

Comment: Already tried.
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links() (View: /localhost/***/resources/views/pages/category.blade.php)`

Comment: you didn't call paginate on Category, its on a different query ... `$category` is a single model not a collection or a paginator. ... `->first()`

Comment: Abdulla: I've added more code now.
lagbox: I only want one category but paginate through the related webshops.

Answer (score 0):

make use of the simplePaginate function instead

```
$category = Category::select()
->where('slug', $slug)
->with(['webshops' => function ($query) {
    $query->groupBy('webshops.id')
    ->orderBy('webshops.name')
    ->with(['brands' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('active', 1)
        ->where('replace_by', NULL)
        ->orderBy('name');
    }])
    ->simplePaginate(3);
}])
->first();
```